# how to implement two thresholds in Plotly gauge chart - Python

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'm using Plotly gauge charts in my Django project. I need to show two thresholds for the upper and lower boundary of some parameter which is being projected in the chart.

here is my chart in `views.py`:

```
gauge_do = go.Figure(go.Indicator(
                                    mode = "gauge+number",
                                    value = 1.7,
                                    domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
                                    title = {'text': "Oxygen [mg/L]"},
                                    gauge = {'axis': {'range': [0, 10]},
                                             'bar': {'color': "salmon"},
                                    'threshold' : {'line': {'color': "red", 'width': 4}, 'thickness': 0.75, 'value': 2}
                                            }
                                    )
                    )
gauge_do.update_layout(font = {'color': "black", 'family': "Arial"}, margin = dict(t=0, b=0, l=5, r=5,), height=230)                    
div_do = opy.plot(gauge_do, auto_open=False, config=config, output_type='div')
```

Here, there is one `threshold` with value of `'value': 2`.

In my case, I want to show the minimum acceptable value and maximum acceptable value by two indicators ( exactly as threshold ), say `min=2` and `max=8`.

the plotly doesnt accept using two `'threshold'`s.

any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/reference/indicator), it seems like they intend `steps` to do this. Something like:

```
gauge_do = go.Figure(
    go.Indicator(
        mode = "gauge+number",
        value = 1.7,
        domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
        title = {'text': "Oxygen [mg/L]"},
        gauge = {'axis': {'range': [0, 10]},
                 'bar': {'color': "salmon"},
                 'steps' : [{
                     'color': 'white',
                     'line': {'color': "red", 'width': 4},
                     'thickness': 0.75,
                     'range': [2,8]}]

        }
    )
)
```

Comment: No it doenst, steps are for the qualitative illustrations, not treshold. i have the same question actually with R..ti add a lower and upper threshold

Comment: It's not really the solution, but a good workaround, in particular I used the "original" threshold for the minimum (so that it overlaps the bar) and the step for the maximum (which, as such, should not have the overlapping bar)